# getUserMedia Not working when inside a function

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

Why is this code not working:

```
videoCallButton.onclick = function()
{navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError);
};
```

but this one It is:

```
videoCallButton.onclick = navigator.getUserMedia(
mediaConstraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError
);
```

and the event onclick works everytime page is loaded, without clicking

```
 videoCallButton.onclick = alert("yes");
```

Comment: Please add some more information, like which language this is (prefferably add a tag).

Comment: Are you trying to invoke getUserMedia without the user clicking on something?  If so, this works in Firefox, but I believe does not in Chrome (especially since Chrome tends to automatically save permissions they don't want getUserMedia to be invokable on load - Firefox defaults to permission for the session only)